# Looking for an axisymetric raytracing library or algorithm

Tags: simulation

I need to raytrace an axisymetric solid, made up of quadrilaterals rotated 360 degrees around Z, split radially into discrete elements. I will need either the source or a pre-built C++ library, so it can be integrated into an existing project.

The naive solution is to simply generate a triangular mesh from the axisymetric mesh, and then raytrace that instead. However, no triangular mesh will 100% accurately represent the original axisymetric mesh. The closer we try to get, the more memory and computation time will be used.

I have been poking around looking for research articles, but I'm coming up with very limited results. Has anyone else had to tackle this problem before?

If there is a solution in C++ that would be great, but if there's an open-source solution in any other language I can always convert it over myself.